# Cannot invoke 'GameSetting.init' with an argument list of type

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

```
import UIKit

struct PropertyKeys {
    static let keyHightScore = "hightScore"
    static let keyLastScore = "lastScore"
    static let keyCurrentScore = "currentScore"
}

class GameSetting: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var hightScore: Int
    var currentScore: Int
    var lastScore: Int

    var life = 3

    override init() {
        hightScore = 0
        currentScore = 0
        lastScore = 0

        super.init()

        loadGameSetting()
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeInteger(hightScore, forKey: PropertyKeys.keyHightScore)
        aCoder.encodeInteger(currentScore, forKey: PropertyKeys.keyCurrentScore)
        aCoder.encodeInteger(lastScore, forKey: PropertyKeys.keyLastScore)
    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        var hightScore = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKeys.keyHightScore)
        var currentScore = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKeys.keyCurrentScore)
        var lastScore = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKeys.keyLastScore)

        self.init(hightScore: Int, currentScore: Int, lastScore: Int) {
            self.hightScore = hightScore
            self.currentScore = currentScore
            self.lastScore = lastScore
        }
    }

    func recordScore(score: Int) {
        if score > hightScore { hightScore = score }

        lastScore = score

        saveGameSetting()
    }

    func saveGameSetting() {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(hightScore, forKey: PropertyKeys.keyHightScore)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(lastScore, forKey: PropertyKeys.keyLastScore)
    }

    func loadGameSetting() {
        hightScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey(PropertyKeys.keyHightScore)
        lastScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey(PropertyKeys.keyLastScore)
    }

    override var description: String {
        return "HighScore: \(self.hightScore), lastScore: \(self.lastScore), currenScore: \(self.currentScore)"
    }

    func reset() {
        currentScore = 0
    }

    func resetHightScore() {
        hightScore = 0
        lastScore = 0

        saveGameSetting()
    }
}
```

What is wrong? I don't understand this error.

I can not find anything on this issue.

I want to finished save and load score data, and I am following this example:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson10.html

Comment: Cannot invoke 'GameSetting.init' with an argument list of type '(hightScore: Int.Type, currentScore: Int.Type, lastScore: Int.Type, () -> ())'

Answer (score 3):

You haven't defined an `init` method with those arguments.  You probably want something like this:

```
required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let hightScore = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKeys.keyHightScore)
    let currentScore = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKeys.keyCurrentScore)
    let lastScore = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKeys.keyLastScore)

    self.init()

    self.hightScore = hightScore
    self.currentScore = currentScore
    self.lastScore = lastScore
}
```

or create a convenience init with the specified arguments:

```
convenience init(highScore: Int, currentScore: Int, lastScore: Int) {
    self.init()
    self.hightScore = highScore
    self.currentScore = currentScore
    self.lastScore = lastScore
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got a misplaced '}' which lead to adding a misplaced `self`

Where you have:

```
required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    var hightScore = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKeys.keyHightScore)
    var currentScore = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKeys.keyCurrentScore)
    var lastScore = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKeys.keyLastScore)

    self.init(hightScore: Int, currentScore: Int, lastScore: Int) {
        self.hightScore = hightScore
        self.currentScore = currentScore
        self.lastScore = lastScore
    }
}
```

I think you want:

```
required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    var hightScore = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKeys.keyHightScore)
    var currentScore = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKeys.keyCurrentScore)
    var lastScore = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKeys.keyLastScore)

    self.init(hightScore:hightScore, currentScore:currentScore, lastScore:lastScore)
}

init(hightScore: Int, currentScore: Int, lastScore: Int) {
    self.hightScore = hightScore
    self.currentScore = currentScore
    self.lastScore = lastScore
}
```

and it doesn't look like there's anyway for the `init` to fail, so there's no reason for it to be failable, and the vars don't get changed, so make them `let`:

```
required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let hightScore = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKeys.keyHightScore)
    let currentScore = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKeys.keyCurrentScore)
    let lastScore = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKeys.keyLastScore)

    self.init(hightScore:hightScore, currentScore:currentScore, lastScore:lastScore)
}
```